# How to make a tall div on the right side of bootstrap layout?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I feel like I am missing something simple here. http://codepen.io/jpmckearin/pen/atdku/

This is what I have:
[image]

This is what I need:
[image]

Code: (see codepen at top of post)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 sm-tile">a</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 sm-tile">b</div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 sm-tile">c</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 tile">d</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 tile">e</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 lg-tile">f</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 tile">g</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 tile">h</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 tile">i</div>
  </div>
</div>

[class*="col-"] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sm-tile {
  height: 100px;
}

.lg-tile {
  height: 600px;
}

.tile {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-10'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 sm-tile">a</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 sm-tile">b</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 sm-tile">c</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 tile">d</div>
        <div class="col-md-8 tile">e</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-md-4 tile">g</div>
        <div class="col-md-8 tile">h</div>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class="col-md-12 tile">i</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 lg-tile">f</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Plunker available here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZfjhTHmecksaV3S2ImKh

Comment: The proportions between the columns is not exactly the same though, going from a 10 to 12 columns available in the grid for the left-hand side of the layout. It could probably be changed but would require some messing with Bootstrap's grid system.